# Regular Expression to Split String

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to split the following string

```
"17. Entertainment costs,16. Employee morale, health, and welfare costs,3. Test"
```

Into

```
17. Entertainment costs
16. Employee morale, health, and welfare costs
3. Test
```

Note the commas in the second string.

I'm trying

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        Regex regex = new Regex( ",[1-9]" );
        string strSplit = "1.One,2.Test,one,two,three,3.Did it work?";
        string[] aCategories = regex.Split( strSplit );
        foreach (string strCat in aCategories) {
            System.Console.WriteLine( strCat );
        }
    }
```

But the #'s don't come through

```
1.One
.Test,one,two,three
.Did it work?
```

Comment: By splitting on ",[1-9]", you will never get the digits in your array aCategories. Maybe try to find the index of ",[1-9]" then use it to keep substrings, hence keeping the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're splitting on (for example) `,2` — the `2` is considered part of the separator, just like the comma. To fix this, you can use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
        Regex regex = new Regex( ",(?=[1-9])" );
```

meaning "a comma, provided the comma is followed immediately by a nonzero digit".

Comment: Thanks everyone! Points all around.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [a lookahead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) `(?=...)`, like in this expression:

```
@",(?=\s*\d+\.)"
```

Remove the `\s*` if you don't want to allow spaces between the `,` and the `N.`.

Comment: I don't think that there are spaces before the numbers.